# How to open the Run window programmatically

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

Everyone knows the Run window that you can open with the shortcut Windows+R or directly in the Windows menu then Run.
I'm wondering how to open this Run window programmatically.
This window seems to be part of explorer.exe.
Does anyone have an idea on it ?

Comment: Why would you want to open the Run window? Can't you execute the programs directly instead of going trough the run command? or am i missing something here? I did try to locate if it were in a separate .exe or something like that, but as you say it seems to be a part of explorer.exe. Have you considered using cmd.exe?

Comment: First of all, re-read the question; they never said *anything* about *running* anything, they simply asked about programmatically opening the Run dialog. Second, the Run dialog has options (check-boxes) to alter how the program/file is run that may not be easy, if at all possible to accomplish using whatever language they are using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `IShellDispatch::FileRun` to achieve this.

See [Using the Windows RunFile dialog - The documented and undocumented way](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/runfiledlg.aspx) for details and sample code.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that it could open say at 8:00 am, then you can use autohotkey and simply write 
`SendInput {Raw}{Lwin}{R}`
and then compile it as an .exe and put it as a cron job

Comment: And what if the Win key combos are disabled?

Comment: Not least of which, autohotkey introduces a whole slew of other issues, including security vulnerabilities

Answer (score 0):

FYI, in Windows 10/11 (havn't checked 8.x) you can open the Run dialog easily by calling:

```
explorer shell:::{2559a1f3-21d7-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0}
```

E.g. in a batch script:

```
start explorer shell:::{2559a1f3-21d7-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0}
```