# Custom Run Dialog Input

Tags: c++, shellexecute

How would I go about starting a Run Dialog window and having my application input a command to start Steam?

I would like my application to open the standard windows run dialog pre-filled with input.

This is what I have tried:

```
HINSTANCE result;
result = ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "rundll32.exe", "steam://connect/192.69.96.168:27023", NULL, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
```

I don't really understand the parameters for ShellExecute and would like some clarification.

**UPDATE**

I think I have gotten it to work:

```
HINSTANCE result;
result = ShellExecute(                            // WinExec is obsolete.
    0,                                        // hwnd
    "open",                                   // operation/verb.
    "steam://connect/192.69.96.168:27023",    // executable.
        "",                                        // parameters.
    NULL,                                     // directory
    SW_SHOW);                                 // how to be displayed
```

Comment: Please clarify: do you want to run something (then you don't need the run dialog) or to open the standard windows run dialog, pre-filled with your input ?

Comment: @Antoine The latter. To open the standard windows run dialog pre-filled with input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2734/Using-the-Windows-RunFile-dialog-The-documented-an), taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738205/how-to-open-the-run-window-programmatically) related question. This will open the run dialog.

Then if your process has the admin rights, you might be able to call `SetWindowText` on the handle of the input box of the dialog, which you'll find with `FindWindowEx` or similar.

I really think it's easier to create your own run dialog which looks like the windows one and calls `ShellExecute` when "ok" is clicked.