# Run win features, that starts by hotkeys, from console/commands

Tags: windows, powershell

How to launch "control windows", that, for example, runs by `win+r` or `win+v`, from console?

I mean something like that:
`ms-settings:display` may be... I know about the way to send keys pressings, but im looking for command exactly.

Comment: URL schemes such as `ms-settings:` are used with Microsoft Store apps, including the Settings app (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58733061/45375) for how to retrieve such an app's URL schemes). By contrast, the two hotkey examples you give relate to internal features of the Windows shell, not separate applications, as far as I know, so I'm guessing that a URL-based approach won't work.

Comment: @mklement0 , i dont mean exactly url. It was just an example. I mean "something", that i can wrote in console, and open windows, that runs by win+r or win+v.

Comment: I think the two things you're looking for are technically unrelated to things you can invoke with a URL such as  `ms-settings:`, hence my clarification. As for the Run dialog (WinKey+R): This has been asked before: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7738205/45375. Not sure about the Clipboard dialog (WinKey+V), but the linked post may provide pointers too.

Comment: To avoid the `ms-settings:` distraction, you could simply state that you're looking for a _programmatic_ way to invoke these features, _from the command line_.